# Video clicks count laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to count the number of clicks on my video using Laravel. I followed  this tutorial I found on Google: http://cameronscott.co/posts/tracking-page-clicks-in-laravel but nothing is working. I clicked on the video and it didn't increment in the database. Here is my code.

Route:

```
Route::get('video/{id}/click','ClickController@clickvideo');
```

Controller:

```
class ClickController extends Controller
{
    public function clickvideo($id){
        $po=User::findorfail($id);
        $po->increment('clicks');
        $po->update();
    }
```

Views:

```
<a href="{{url('video/{$proo->id}/click')}}" class="js-click-video" style="border:none; background:none;">
    <video class="video1" id="cb" preload="auto" data-post-id="{$proo->id}"  style=" overflow: hidden; width: 30vh; object-fit: cover; float:left; clear:both;
           height: auto; padding-left:2%;   margin-top:0px; border:2px solid white;  cursor:pointer; "><source  src="{{$proo->intro_video}}#t=13" playsinline alt="Video Unavailable"   id="" ></source>
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.js-click-video').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var post=$(this).closest('.video1');
    var postId=post.attr('data-post-id');
    registerPostClick(postid);
});

function registerPostClick(postid){
    $.ajaxSetup({

        headers:{
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: '/video/' + postId + '/click',
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a mustache in your variable name here:

```
data-post-id="{$proo->id}"
```

Should be

```
data-post-id="{{$proo->id}}"
```

This should also be:

```
*{{url('video/{$proo->id}/click')}}*
{{url('video/' . $proo->id .'/click')}}
```

Also, this is not necessary

```
 $po->update();
```

Comment: @Ploaris the url you told me to put is giving me syntax error the one I had dosen't give me one, but I corrected the data post id. Still nothing is happening.

Comment: Oops, I made a typo. It should be:
{{url('video/' . $proo->id .'/click')}}

Comment: @Ploaris I fixed it. Sadly the click doesn't increment in the database. Is my Javascript code correct? I know my controller isn't the problem.

Comment: You are using Ajax method Post on a Get Route, also findorfail should be findorFail with a capital F. Also, you are using the database table User:: to find the video ID, are you sure this is the correct table?

Comment: Yes I am using the correct table. In the users table there is a column called clicks. Also I switched the get route to post route, and I put the capital F on fail just now and that didn't do anything. Ugh I'm so sorry I've been trying to get this to work for the past three days now sorry if i'm taking up your time.

Comment: In the users table, what column are you using to identify the video_id? You should not be using the users table for videos. You should have created a separate table for the videos so you could use their id's. Also, can I see your method output that you are using to send data to your blade view? Also, what does your users database table look like?

Comment: I am using the users table for the video. Basically the users table is their profile it has their first name,last name, video,email,password. its like I want to say how many time they viewed their profile by clicking on their video.  Hopefully that's not confusing.

Comment: @jmike sadly no I didn’t and still there is no tutorial to show. I’m really trying my best to get this

Comment: @t5050 the tutorial that you posted seems to be missing information honestly i think the issue has something to do with     `var post=$(this).closest('.video1');`  i dont think it grabbing the right item

Comment: @t5050 i am trying to figure it out as well

Comment: @jmike I changed it to video instead nothing works. I really don’t know. I click the video and it doesn’t increment it in the database

Comment: @jmike have you tried using vue.js and axios instead?

Comment: @Polaris yah i may have to make a button component  and increment it that way seem like more work but i will try it out now